# Getting Incomplete User Details Info from OneLogin

Tags: onelogin

I am trying to get user detail info from onelogin after getting token successfully.
But getting some parameters null. I have used below code:

```
    val config = OIDCConfiguration.Builder()
           .clientId("XXXXXXX")
           .issuer("XXXXXXXX")
           .redirectUrl("XXXXXXX")
           .scopes(listOf("openid", "profile", "email"))
           .isDebug(true)
           .build()
    
    OneLoginOIDC.initialize(this.applicationContext,config)
    val oidcClient = OneLoginOIDC.getClient()
```

Now using `oidcClient?.signIn()` to get token in `onSuccess` callback and after getting token when i tried to get user info object using `oidcClient?.getUserInfo()` I get userinfo object like: UserInfo(sub=123936207, email=hksharma@q3tech.com, preferredUsername=null, name=Harish Kr Sharma, updatedAt=null, givenName=null, familyName=null, groups=null)

Here, getting updatedAt, givenName, familyName, groups and preferredUsername parameters value null.
Also how to get some custom additional information added by backened team to onelogin portal